# How can I manipulate HTML DOM elements using Object Oriented Programming with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I recently got into OOP and I am trying to build something with it. The first project is a BMI calculator but I have gotten stuck. I have managed to get the BMI results to display on the console but implementing them into the UI is difficult. I have tried to get the calculation results by appending it to created Ui elements but that does not work and I am getting an error code. The code is below

```js
class CalculatorInput {
  constructor(height, weight) {
    this.height = height;
    this.weight = weight;
  }
}

class Calculation {
  calculateResults(calculation) {
    console.log(calculation)
  }
}


class UI {
  displayResults(bmiCalc) {
    const textElement = document.createElement('h1');
    const display = document.querySelector('.display');
  }
}



document.querySelector('.input').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  const height = document.querySelector('#height').value;
  const weight = document.querySelector('#weight').value;
  const calculate = Math.floor(weight / Math.pow(height, 2));


  const bmiCalc = new CalculatorInput(height, weight);

  const ui = new UI;

  const calculation = new Calculation;

  calculation.calculateResults(calculate);

  ui.displayResults(bmiCalc);
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card {
  background-color: #B4F767;
  margin: auto auto;
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Caladea', serif;
}

.input {
  padding: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-family: 'Caladea', serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

button {
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: block;
  background-color: #3B78F1;
  border: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  font-family: 'Caladea', serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.display {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Caladea', serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <h1>BMI Calculator</h1>
  <div>
    <form class="input">
      <label for="">Height in M</label>
      <input type="text" id="height">
      <label for="">Weight in KG</label>
      <input type="text" id="weight">
      <div>
        <button class="calculate" type="submit">Calculate</button>
      </div>
      <div class="display">

      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: You use objects, but it is not OOP: you separate data and calculation, but it should be together. I recommend to create BMI object with setWidth, setHeight and getValue methods.

Comment: Start with `display.textContent=\`Height: ${bmiCalc.height}m, weight: ${bmiCalc.height}kg\``

Comment: Thanks, Jan turon. I made it work. Thank you so much.